# Can I find my iPhone if it's lost and turned off?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

My iPhone lost when I was skiing. I think its in the snow and nobody can find it. I'm sure that my iPhone has about 40% charge but it turned off because of the freezing.
Is there any way to find my iPhone with any apps when its off?

Answer (score 6):

With the phone off there is no way to locate it from remote. And to be honest, a few days embedded in snow will not only kill the remaining charge in the phone but also the electronics itself (water will slowly get in).

Comment: Is there really no way ? I think that an alarm set rings even when the iPhone is turned off. When the alarm is ringing, the iPhone turns on its screen. At this moment, the iPhone may connect to the mobile network...

Comment: If it is turned off (powered off, Apple logo shows when turned on again), no alarm will wake up the phone. And depending on your SIM settings you will need to enter your SIM PIN to active the mobile connection as well.